# HGROUP element removed from the HTML5 Specification. What alternative technique can be used instead?

Tags: html, w3c, semantic-markup, web-standards

As some of you would of heard the `hgroup` element is being removed from the [HTML5 Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/). (For more info, see the [W3C HTML Working Group's decision on request to drop `hgroup` from HTML5](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html-admin/2013Apr/0003.html) on the W3C's Public Mailing List archives.)

Now I'm currently working on the redesign of a site using this tag that creates a way of adding a sub heading.

My current thoughts are to just add another `hX` tag under the main header, but I'm not sure if this would be semantic enough to do so.

```
 <h1>Darren Reay</h1>
 <h2>A developing web developer</h2>
 <p>Hello World</p>
```

Could anyone either come up with a alternative for using sub headers or at least point me in the right direction?

Comment: What problem can you solve with `hgroup` that you can't solve as easily without ? Can you make this question more concrete ?

Comment: @dystroy I've edited the question to add my current thoughts to hopefully clarify the question. Thanks

Comment: What is wrong with what you have? That is how you are supposed to create headings and subheadings. The `hgroup` tag was just to wrap around them to show they were related. You could do the same with a normal div.

Comment: @jimjimmy1995 but would search engines recognise them two headings as grouped with just a div surrounding them? I thought divs were meaningless to search engines. They are just hooks for css I thought.

Comment: @DarrenReay How do you think they did it before the hgroup tag?

Comment: @DarrenReay Are hgroup tags meaningful to search engines? I kinda doubt it.

Comment: @juhana I thought the reason for these tags were to give meaning to content for computers.

Comment: That's right, but that doesn't mean all of them are meaningful for every computer.

Comment: According to [Steve Faulkner's research](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html/2013Apr/0004.html), `<div>` and `<p>` are more commonly used for a tagline/subheading than an `<h?>` element. Use one of those two.

Comment: FWIW, the use case for `<hgroup>` was to hide `<h?>` elements from the document outline when they were being (mis)used to augment a higher level heading rather than to introduce a subsection.

Comment: @Alohci yeah, your right I've read that it is used to hide the additional h tag. The hgroup made sense whereas having just a very short p tag after a heading is very strange as you wouldn't type a word document out and have a very short paragraph consisting of a couple of words after the heading. Even having another h tag is also a little strange as it gives a sub heading more value then the headings that appear after it. It is something I think they need to sort out for the future.

Comment: I can see <hgroup> in the spec: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-hgroup-element

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A couple of points to consider:

1. Even if the tag is removed from the HTML5 specification, it doesn't mean that it would stop working overnight. Browsers keep backwards compatibility for a long time (AFAIK most if not all browsers still render `<font>` correctly!)
2. Even if the browsers would drop support overnight, they'd still render the page correctly because I don't think the hgroup tag adds any inherent styling and (modern) browsers are very lenient in allowing tags they don't recognize.
3. I might be reading the question wrong, but between the lines it sounds like you've been misusing the hgroup tag anyway. (It's not allowed to contain anything other than header elements.)

I don't see any problem in either dropping the tags completely or replacing them with divs.

Comment: Yeah, I think the question is a little vague. I've only ever used h tags within the hgroup. So from what I gather from your answer browsers will still recognise hgroup for now and until a new tag is released for subheading the code is semantically correct?

Comment: Now that I read the discussion you linked to, it specifically says that they consider removing it from the specification because **no browser has implemented it**. So you're pretty safe. It's very unlikely that they'd come up with a new tag to replace it, because `<h2>` *already* means a subheading.

Answer (score 27):

The HTML5 spec now includes advice on how to mark up [Subheadings, subtitles, alternative titles and taglines](http://w3c.github.io/html/common-idioms-without-dedicated-elements.html#subheadings-subtitles-alternative-titles-and-taglines#sub-head)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Pretty much what I thought. I would give you a plus 1 if I could :(

Comment: New link: http://w3c.github.io/html/common-idioms-without-dedicated-elements.html#subheadings-subtitles-alternative-titles-and-taglines

Comment: What??? I see nothing on [that linked page](http://w3c.github.io/html/common-idioms-without-dedicated-elements.html#subheadings-subtitles-alternative-titles-and-taglines#sub-head) about subheadings, nor subtitles, nor alternative titles, nor taglines.

Answer (score 8):

I would go with the alternative suggested by the W3C in the [drop hgroup change proposal](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/wiki/ChangeProposals/dropHgroup) proposed by Lars Gunther and use header and paragraph.

Your example would look like this

```
<header>
    <h1>Darren Reay</h1>
    <p>A developing web developer</p>
</header>
```

I feel this reads correctly and semantically.

Comment: What should we use for substituting `<hgroup>` inside the `<header>` element (e.g.: for site title)? Can a `<header>` be inside a `<header>`>

Answer (score 4):

It's 2022 and I see `hgroup` is present in the spec:
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-hgroup-element

[image]

Looks like `hgroup` is acclaimed again, but that's kinda strange. It was in the spec, then it disappeared, and now it's back again...

On the other hand, https://validator.w3.org/ complains about the following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<title>Title</title>
<hgroup>
  <h2>Heading</h2>
  <p>Subheading</p>
</hgroup>
</html>
```

[image]

> Content model for element hgroup:
> Zero or more p elements, followed by one h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, or h6 element, followed by zero or more p elements, optionally intermixed with script-supporting elements.

But it behaves like it's broken because there are exactly zero p elements, followed by one h2 element, followed by zero or more p elements.

And on top of that, MDN says `hgroup` is supported by every browser:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/hgroup
[image]

At the same time MDN says to avoid using `hgroup` because it does not work properly with assistive technologies:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#heading_content

[image]

I'm posting an answer, but I can't stop myself from asking the question:
why there's such a mess with `hgroup`?

Answer (score 0):

This is the technique that I currently use on my personal site to achieve the effect of having a heading with a sub-title:

```
<header>
  <h1>
    <a href="http://www.jdclark.org/">Jordan Clark</a>
    <small>Personal and Professional Website</small>
  </h1>
</header>
```

(Then, of course, I simply use CSS to re-style the `<small>` element. I also personally believe that my technique is more semantically accurate than just using a paragraph -- and although I am no SEO expert, I am sure that by keeping the sub-title text within the `h1` would give it higher value than a basic paragraph.)